# Is it proper to use a default constructor with polymorphism?

Tags: c++, oop

I basically have something like this:

```
class CGlToolBase
{
public:
    CGlToolBase(void)
    {

    }
    virtual void OnMouseDown(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnMouseMove(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnMouseUp(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnKeyDown(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnLDoubleClick(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    ~CGlToolBase(void);
};

class CGlToolSelect : public CGlToolBase
{
   bool selected;
public:
    CGlToolSelect(void)
    {
     selected = false;
    }
    virtual void OnMouseDown(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnMouseMove(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnMouseUp(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnKeyDown(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual void OnLDoubleClick(CGlEngine &glEngine, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    ~CGlToolSelect(void);
};
```

In my select tool I set selected to false. Is this the correct way to do it if I do something like this:

```
CGlToolBase *tool = new CGlToolSelect;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly legal and acceptable.

However, some notes:

Your destructor should be virtual.  If any class has virtual methods (abstract or not), you should have a public virtual (abstract?) destructor (so `delete` calls the children destructors) or a protected non-virtual destructor (which prevents the superclass from being `delete`d as a superclass (it must be `delete`d as a subclass, thus calling the appropriate destructor)).

You may want to use initializers to set `selected` in the constructor:

```
CGlToolSelect() :
    selected(false)
{
}
```

Comment: I use `(void)` because I'm a rebel. (It's a stylistic issue and nothing more; to me, it looks better.)

Comment: @GMan, Alright; it's just something I learned to avoid, but I can't remember why right now.

Comment: Its called *destructor*, not *deconstructor*. Regarding your virtual dtor guideline - please take a look at Sutters [Virtuality](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) (or at least #4 in the summary).

Comment: ...or you can use protected non-virtual inheritance.

Comment: Since you are adding style advice, I would not write the base constructor (empty initialization list, empty body).

Comment: @strager: In C++ there is no difference between `void foo()` and `void foo(void)`, in both cases it represents a function taking no arguments. You probably learned that in C, where `void foo(void)` means a function taking no arguments, while `void foo()` is a function taking a fixed unknown number of arguments. In the first case, calls like `foo(5)` will be flagged as an error by the compiler in the first case, while it will be silently accepted in the second case. But again, in C++ both mean exactly the same.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas, I understand that about C, but I wasn't sure if there was a difference in C++.  I checked, and it seems there isn't, so I removed that from my answer.  @Georg Fritzsche and @Clark Gaebe, You're right; I have never needed a protected destructor, so I never considered this.  I also have problems remembering "destructor" or "deconstructor"; sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it proper to use a default constructor with polymorphism?
>
> CGlToolBase *tool = new CGlToolSelect;

Sure - you notice that the argument to `new` is `CGlToolSelect` - at the point the memory is allocated and the constructor called, the exact class is known to the compiler.  The correct derived-class constructor is used without any need for `virtual` dispatch.  Which constructor you use, and specifically whether it's a default constructor (i.e. has no non-defaulted arguments) makes no difference at all: any one will work perfectly.

Separately - after the construction, the calling scope only has the `CGlToolBase*` object to go by and doesn't necessarily know the real run-time type of the object at the time it's deleted, which is why to get the run-time type appropriate constructor used you need to look it up using a record in the pointed-to object: virtual functions create exactly such a record (an entry in the virtual dispatch table), that's why making the destructor virtual solves this problem of invoking the correct destructor.  In your specific example, it may not seem to matter as the derived class doesn't introduce any additional members with destructors of their own that need to be invoked, but remember that your derived class can itself be derived from, and those more-derived classes may introduce data members that need proper destruction in order to release resources such as heap memory, file handles, shared memory, locks etc..  Again, making the destructor virtual ensures the most-derived class's destructor is properly called, and the classes call back through the immediate base classes to the base class destructor.